# Is it possible to add an updated answer to a closed question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

To this question:
[Paragraph direction missing in Adobe illustrator CC 2018](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120775/paragraph-direction-missing-in-adobe-illustrator-cc-2018),
there is a better answer, which is the only way to solve the problem today. The problem is that the question is closed and cannot be answered, but it is shown in the first results of Google.
I spent long hours talking on Adobe's support center, time which could have been saved if the correct answer had appeared here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/il_he/creative-cloud/help/change-install-language.html

Comment: Its probably better that you reask a simiar question and then adress this in a new answer. Yes i have enough points to cast reopen but that does not halp i still need 5 others to concurr

Answer (score 2):

Not really. But:

1. Anybody who already answered before closure can change their post.
2. You can vote for reopening. This would reset the question if others agree to open.

Comment: **1.** I have never commented there, and I have nothing to edit anyway.


**2.** I do not have enough points to request a reopening.